# Bizspark - Moving WebApp to `Basic` tier

Tags: azure, microsoft

I have 3 web apps running via the BizSpark programme on Azure. The apps run on the **Free** tier at the moment. I want to add a custom domain to the apps so I know I have to upgrade it to the **Basic** tier and this will move all my web apps to operate under it.

My question is - will this update automatically null and void my free monthly credits or even consume them at a higher rate on the **Basic** tier?

Comment: I don't want to sound like a smartass but have you tried asking them?

Comment: Yea I know. I wondered if I'd get a quicker result on here though :)